# Magento 2. What is the entity/class responsible for calculating the discount amount?

Tags: magento2, discount, coupon

- What is the entity/class responsible for calculating the discount amount?
- Where is this discount amount calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RulesApplier` with its method `applyRule()` that calls `setDiscountData()` where the discount amount fields are setted.

```
$item->setDiscountAmount($discountData->getAmount());
$item->setBaseDiscountAmount($discountData->getBaseAmount());
$item->setOriginalDiscountAmount($discountData->getOriginalAmount());
$item->setBaseOriginalDiscountAmount($discountData->getBaseOriginalAmount());
```